# Invalid Pipe Argument in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

This is my **HTML**:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let chat of all_chats" (click)="goChat(chat)">
        <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img src="{{chat.student.picture_url}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <p item-right>{{chat.last_msg.date |date: 'shortTime'}}</p>
        <h2>{{chat.student.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{chat.last_msg.text}}</p>
        <p *ngIf="!chat.last_msg.text">Session Request</p>   
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And when I enter chatlist page I get this **error**:

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '14/08/2017 06:17 AM' for pipe    'DatePipe' , it occured in any pages i use pipe in it

Comment: what is the value of  chat.last_msg.date ? 
it works for me .. the value of my date is "2017-08-14T06:53:58.476Z"

have you try the docs ?
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: this is the value 14/08/2017 06:17 AM

Comment: or you can try to use Customepipe or try using moment it will make it more easier .. because it needs to be convert to format that angular pipe needs .

Comment: i tried momment module but still gives me **Invalid date** output

Comment: im using angular2-moment so far no issue . and every flexible in any date format. in code or via pipe

Comment: have you tried moment with this format **14/08/2017 06:17 AM** ?

Comment: yes ithink do you want to see it as answer ? what date format are you expecting ? i will try it ..

Answer (score 3):

Using `MomentModule` not custome pipe.

try doing this.

**1**. you need to install the library `angular2-moment`

```
npm install angular2-moment --save
```

**2**. in your page.module add `MomentModule` to `imports`

then

on html

```
<h1>{{ chat.last_msg.date| amParse:'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A' | amDateFormat:'hh:mm A'  }} </h1>
```

Comment: oh it works now thanks @Jake , i didn't use **amParse** and **amDateFormat**  together thats why i got invalid date

Comment: Nice! glad to hear that.  :) same concept when you use moment in you code 
moment(chat.last_msg.date,['DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A']).format('hh:mm A');
you need to indicate the previous or the original date format before you convert it to your desire format .. :) cheers !